# Using Base R, how would I accomplish the following tasks?

Tags: r, data-science, linear-regression, computer-science

Using base R, I've created a model and am trying to test it using the predict function to return the probability of making more than $50k in a year, turn it into a usable categorical variable, and then add the predicted outcome to my test dataframe dataToModel2 using the following coding and am unsure if I've done it right. Have I correctly fed my binary model prediction values into the dataframe used to test my models and what would represents the real outcomes here?

```
probabilities <- predict(theModel, newdata = dataToModel2 , type = "response")   
dataToModel2$predictions <- probabilities > .5
str(dataToModel2)
```

If so, is there a formula to use that calculates the accuracy, false negatives, false positives, and positive predict values? I understand slightly that it has to do with making both the column for real outcome and the column for my model's predictions the same units(making real outcome True/False or 1/0), but am unsure on how to do that or why it is necessary.

Comment: Just doing `table(y, yhat)` where `y` is the observed dependent variable in the test data and `yhat`is the predicted value (i.e., `predictions` in the data you have, that should be enough to calculate what you want.  Whether or not they are in the same units or coded the same way is immaterial as long as you know what to look for.

Comment: You may want to familiarize yourself with what a [confusion matrix](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=confusion+matrix&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) is - good luck!

Comment: What could be the reason for a confusion matrix adding the True Negative and False Negative, leaving the True Negative as  (TN + FN) and the False Negative as 0. The same thing is happening with my True Positive and False Positive as my True Positive appears as (TP + TN) and my True Negative is 0.